# Tell DownloadManager to overwrite existing file

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm experiencing that `DownloadManager` doesn't overwrite an existing file but creates a new File, e.g. `world-1.map` instead of just `world.map`.

Is there a way to telling him to overwrite an existing file or a workaround without having to add new privileges or hundreds of lines of code?

Comment: If file download is complete, it will create a new file(if the name is same then add a number to it). If the file is partially downloaded it, it resumes where to end. Still you want to override the file, then you write logic to check file name first then proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked a little bit with the `DownloadManager`, I've never experienced this behavior though, because I deleted the file every time before re-downloading it.
Does this behavior occur even when you explicitly specify the path with one of these methods :

`setDestinationInExternalFilesDir()`

`setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()`

If not you should give it a try.

If it doesn't work though, you can delete the previously downloaded content, you need to store the ID of the download somewhere to be able to delete it. This way :

```
downloadManager.remove(ids);
```

And download the other file afterward.

Comment: I use `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` and experience the behavior. Deleting the old file is not a good option, because when the download fails then there is nothing. It would be better to have the old file than nothing. But I'm thinking about renaming the old file before downloading the new one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This is my work around. I am not sure if there's anything more technical, but this works for me.

First, I check if file exist. 
Then, I delete old file before downloading new one.

```
File oldV = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/foldername/filename");     

if(oldV.exists()){
    oldV.delete();
}

//codes for DownloadManager to download files.
```